# Does the GHZ of A CPU Make A Huge Difference

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I am currently running an i3-2330M @ 2.2GHZ -- I was looking at 5th Gen Intel® Core™ i3-5010U processor.  I understand obviously that the new one would be a 5th Gen and it's a 5010U which is obviously higher than a 2330M, BUT would the GHZ be higher?

I am just wanting to make sure that this laptop would be an upgrade and not so close to current specs I won't be able to tell a difference.

Comment: You can check all intel CPU spec sheet on ark.intel.com and that i3-5010U have a CPU clock speed of 2.1GHz, and your i3-2330M has CPU clock speed of 2.2GHz, so it is actually lower. Whether it will perform better or not - it really depends on the rest of the laptop, and what you do with it.

Comment: @Darius - thank you for that site, that will be very beneficial!!!!

Comment: Am not a subject matter expert..however as per my understanding best performance is obtained when all components complement each other. I believe i5 CPU with 2 GB RAM is poor configuration that i3 with 4 GB RAM for day to day computing. The higher CPU speed plays a role when one is doing very specific CPU intensive tasks. For practical usage overall system specs plays more role.

Comment: Remember that power consumption makes a big difference, and Intel takes power consumption very seriously. You're comparing an old type M processor with a new type U processor that has the same number of cores and threads but is clocked only 100 MHz lower, a difference of less than 5%. In practice, the newer processor will fact be slightly faster in practically all applications (see my answer to the linked question), yet consume **far** less power. You might not see a significant performance difference, but you **will** get much longer battery life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance depends on several factors. The short answer, not really. The performance difference between 2.20 and 2.10 GHz is unnoticeable. The major differences between 2nd and 5th Gen. Intel core i processors are a couple of added features, power consumption and data/RAM handling differences. In the end, it really depends on what you need, and what is cost efficient.

I see that the 5010U has IntelHD 5500 graphics, while the 2330M has IntelHD 3000, so the new processor would play videos/games faster.

Comment: The OP is not using fourth generation (*Haswell*). He's currently using second generation (*Sandy Bridge*). There's a huge difference in performance, especially per watt, between *Sandy Bridge* and fifth-generation *Broadwell*, far more than enough to make up for the slower clock speed.

Comment: The i3-2330M is made on a 32nm process. The i3-5010U is made on a 14nm process. The newer fifth-generation part is likely to outperform the much older second-generation processor—even though type-U processors consume far less power than type-M processors! (Note that neither processor has Turbo Boost, and both are dual-core with Hyper-Threading Technology.)

Comment: @DragonLord Answer updated with some of your suggestions and corrections. Thank you.